# Call gazebo/set_model_state without resetting position

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I asked this over at ROS forums as well, but I'm in a bit of a rush in this situation.
Hi, everyone. I'm currently trying to use gazebo/set_ model_state in a C++ program to set a robot's velocity. My preliminary code is below:

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
#include <gazebo_msgs/SetModelState.h>
#include <cstdlib>
//I'm going to implement user-specified twist values later.
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc,argv,"robot_mover_mark_two");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::SetModelState>("/gazebo/set_model_state");
  gazebo_msgs::SetModelState setmodelstate;
  gazebo_msgs::ModelState modelstate;
  modelstate.model_name = "my_robot";
  modelstate.reference_frame = "world";

  geometry_msgs::Twist model_twist;
  model_twist.linear.x = 1.0;
  model_twist.linear.y = 1.0;
  model_twist.linear.z = 0.0;
  model_twist.angular.x = 0.25;
  model_twist.angular.y = 0.0;
  model_twist.angular.z = 0.0;
  modelstate.twist = model_twist;

  setmodelstate.request.model_state = modelstate;

  if (client.call(setmodelstate))
  {
    ROS_INFO("BRILLIANT!!!");
    ROS_INFO("%f, %f",modelstate.pose.position.x,modelstate.pose.position.y);
  }  
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service ");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;  
}
```

I noticed that every time I run the command, the robot's position is reset to the origin in the Gazebo simulation environment. Are the position parameters set to zero by default if I don't include them in the rosservice call? If so, are there any ways I can use this code and have the model stay in the current position (i.e. just change velocity/twist on the fly)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6503/call-gazebo/set_model_state-without-resetting-position/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sammiL](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4200/sammil/) on 2017-12-04**:
you need one more line:

```
  setmodelstate.request.model_state = modelstate;//request line is important
```

or you will see the error:
Updating ModelState: model [] does not exist

check here: https://answers.ros.org/question/12116/calling-gazebo-service-set_model_state-in-c-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe the position is set to zero by default.

You can try to get the model state first:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm#GetModelStateExample.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-07-02**:
Thank you. I'm going to try that right now.